# Good practises of a knowledge base for users of a scientific open source project: a forum?

Tags: github

I have a [scientific open source project in GitHub for a software aimed at creating three dimensional representations of geographical time-space](https://github.com/theworldisnotflat/shriveling_world). The tool will be soon in version 1, functional, and I want to prepare for its use by a larger community, possibly dozens of people. For this I wish to create a **knowledge base for the software users**. GitHub can be used for bug management, but does not seem adapted to foster such a knowledge base. Is a forum the best solution? Which forum? A wiki?

Related example is [sDNA](https://sdna.cardiff.ac.uk/sdna/support/) which invites to send questions to a gis.stackexchange. This solution needs an existing community.

What are the best practices of **users oriented knowledge base** and what guidance could I receive in order to set it up?